# Sytems running out of memory when Postgresql connection is established

Tags: php, postgresql

I have built an api that is called 20 times in a second to perform a function that establishes connection to a postgresql but anytime the call is made the system memory gets full. I am a novie in postgresql and any assistance will be appreciated. Below is my php code

```
try
{
$input=file_get_contents("php://input");
$pgconn = new PgSql();
$selectRecords="SELECT  messageid, msisdn, smsmessage, serviceid, isbilled, linkid FROM sdpmtn_mt.smssendingtable WHERE priority = 0 LIMIT 1";
foreach($pgconn->getRows($selectRecords) as $rows){
    $msisdn = $rows->msisdn;
    $message = $rows->smsmessage;
    $serviceid = $rows->serviceid;
    $isbilled = $rows->isbilled;
    $linkid = $rows->linkid;
    $msgid = $rows->messageid;
    
   }
}
catch(Exception $e)
{ 
   print $e->getMessage();
}
```

I am calling this API twenty times in a second. Please assist with any configurations I have to make.

Comment: What type of connection pooling are you using?

Comment: Haven't done PHP in a long time and never did the combination with Postgress, but I think you should store the $pgconn somewhere else instead of in the call. You now open a connection 20 times a second. Instead of opening one connection and keep using that one.

Comment: What error are you getting or how are you diagnosing this?

Comment: @Codeaurcan u suggest a better way to do this?